# i CAnt display items from appsync api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, aws-appsync

import logo from './logo.svg';
i need to list items from my appsync api in my react app ...i cant display as it says the error its undefined ...which i mentioned bellow the code..i know my code is wrong can somebody guide me

````
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
import { listTestModels } from "./graphql/queries/list";
import './App.css';


function App() {

  const [list, setBook] = useState(null);

  const getBook = async () => {
    // make a call to appsync api
    const list = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listTestModels));

    setBook(list.data.listTestModels.items);

  }

  const viewBook = () => {
    if (list) {
**it shows error after this **
      return (<article>
        <h3>{list.data.listTestModels.items}</h3>
        <p>{list.Location}</p>
        <p>{list.Email}</p>
      </article>)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <section className="book-section">
        <button onClick={() => getBook()}>Get book details</button>
        <hr />
        {viewBook()}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;```


**it shows error App.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'listTestModels')**
````

Comment: The error is explicit : `list.data` is undefined

Comment: how can i fix it

Comment: You'll need to call your async function in a `useEffect` in order for this to work.

Comment: i dont know to do it

Comment: Well, `list.data` is undefined. You know that `const list = await API.graphql(...)`. So...? Instead of immediately asking "How can I fix it?" follow the hint, try to debug, try to `console.log(list)` to see what's in it, to see if your Graphql call works as intended, etc. Attempt some debug.

Answer (score 0):

`list.data` is undefined. Change the condition to `list && list.data`

```
const viewBook = () => {
    if (list  && list.data) {...}
}
```

But if the `data` key doesn't exist in the `list` object . It will never render the `viewBook`.

Comment: What if `list` _never_ has a `data` key? What if the `API.graphql` call is wrong and never works? At this point there is no information to give a definitive answer. Many things can be wrong

Comment: Yeah , if the `list.data` doesn't exist it will not render the `viewbook`. OP needs to check the API response and shape of the object.